# My code give me this problem "Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps". The function is outside the stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

```
httpErrorHandle(
          response: response,
          context: context,
          onSuccess: () async {

            Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                context, HomeScreen.routeName, (route) => false);
          });
```

I have this code in an asynchronous function outside stateful widget and there is this problem "Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps.
Try rewriting the code to not reference the 'BuildContext'. "

I've tried using mounted as I've seen on the internet but it doesn't work because i'm non on a stateful widget

Comment: You can use `context.mounted` when in a stateless widget.